# Using Exists when Union All is present in the Sub Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wanted to modify the query I wrote using the `IN` operator to using the `Exists` operator. However, the problem is that I have `union all` in my subquery. As I do not have much experience with  using exists in such scenario I was looking for some help.

This was the initial query:

```
select APP_NUM,SBM_INDV_ID 
from T1004_APP_INDV indv 
where INDV.APP_NUM = 'T23952717' 
and INDV.SBM_INDV_ID in
  (select EMPL.INDV_ID 
   from DC_EMPLOYMENT EMPL 
   where EMPL.LOST_EMPLOYMENT_SW = 'N' 
   and EMPL.TERMINATION_DT is null 
   and (EMPL.EFF_END_DT is null 
     or EMPL.EFF_END_DT >= TRUNC(SYSDATE))     
   union all
   select UNEARN.INDV_ID 
   from DC_UNEARNED_INCOME UNEARN 
   where UNEARN.EFF_END_DT is null 
   or UNEARN.EFF_END_DT >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)  
   union all
   select RBINC.INDV_ID 
   from DC_ROOM_BOARD_INCOME RBINC 
   where RBINC.EFF_END_DT is null 
   or RBINC.EFF_END_DT >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
   union all
   select SELFEMP.INDV_ID 
   from DC_SELF_EMP_INCOME SELFEMP 
   where SELFEMP.EFF_END_DT is null 
   or SELFEMP.EFF_END_DT >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
);
```

I tried changing the initial query as follows:

```
select APP_NUM,SBM_INDV_ID 
from T1004_APP_INDV APPINDV 
where APPINDV.APP_NUM = 'T23952717' 
and exists
  (select EMPL.INDV_ID 
   from DC_EMPLOYMENT EMPL 
   where APPINDV.SBM_INDV_ID = EMPL.INDV_ID 
   and EMPL.LOST_EMPLOYMENT_SW = 'N' 
   and EMPL.TERMINATION_DT is null 
   and (EMPL.EFF_END_DT is null 
     or EMPL.EFF_END_DT >= TRUNC(SYSDATE))     
   union all
   select UNEARN.INDV_ID 
   from DC_UNEARNED_INCOME UNEARN 
   where APPINDV.SBM_INDV_ID = UNEARN.INDV_ID 
   and UNEARN.EFF_END_DT is null 
   or UNEARN.EFF_END_DT >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)  
   union all
   select RBINC.INDV_ID 
   from DC_ROOM_BOARD_INCOME RBINC 
   where APPINDV.SBM_INDV_ID = RBINC.INDV_ID 
   and RBINC.EFF_END_DT is null 
   or RBINC.EFF_END_DT >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
   union all
   select SELFEMP.INDV_ID 
   from DC_SELF_EMP_INCOME SELFEMP 
   where APPINDV.SBM_INDV_ID = SELFEMP.INDV_ID 
   and SELFEMP.EFF_END_DT is null 
   or SELFEMP.EFF_END_DT >= TRUNC(SYSDATE));
```

Is the second query correct? Does it produce the same result as the previous query?

Thanks

Comment: You have the data, the tables, the database and the code to test this, but you are asking us if the query is syntactically correct and if it produces the same results??????

Comment: To my eyes it produces the same results for the small data set I am working with. Like I mentioned, I have never worked on a scenario where I have used exists with union all present in the sub query. Is this the appropriate way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think splitting this into separate queries makes it simpler for the optimizer:

```
where APPINDV.APP_NUM = 'T23952717' and
      ( exists (select 1 
                from DC_EMPLOYMENT EMPL 
                where APPINDV.SBM_INDV_ID = EMPL.INDV_ID and
                      EMPL.LOST_EMPLOYMENT_SW = 'N' and
                      EMPL.TERMINATION_DT is null and
                     (EMPL.EFF_END_DT is null or EMPL.EFF_END_DT >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
               ) or
        exists (select 1
                from DC_UNEARNED_INCOME UNEARN 
                where APPINDV.SBM_INDV_ID = UNEARN.INDV_ID and
                      ( UNEARN.EFF_END_DT is null and or UNEARN.EFF_END_DT >= TRUNC(SYSDATE) )
               ) or
        . . .
     )
```